# Sagemaker processing job local mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have 3 processing jobs to run, I want to setup `Sagemaker processing job local mode` ( without Sagemaker pipeline ) for running Sagemaker processing jobs locally on my machine. Can someone help me with this, if you have done it before. What all prerequisites and how to set up it locally.